# Habilitar Imagens na DataGridView

Tags: c#

Bom dia, pessoal!

sou novo aqui, desculpar se estou postando minha dúvida no lugar errado. Mais vamos la.

Tenho um formulário que tem uma DataGridView, onde nessa grid tem os campos que foi feito pelo assistente da própria . Minha dúvida é pq queria adicionar uma coluna que iria receber um icon que seria o meu Butão para excluir os registro. 
Icon foi colocado com sucesso, mais quando vou carregar o frm não aparece o icone que coloquei, e aparece um outro de erro.
Estou utilisando visual studio C# 2017
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi sua pergunta mas acredito que você esteja procurando o componente
[DataGridViewButtonColumn](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn?view=netframework-4.8).

O `DataGridViewButtonColumn` é uma classe especializado do tipo  `DataGridViewColumn` usada para hospedar logicamente células que respondem a entradas simples do usuário. Um `DataGridViewButtonColumn` tem associado um `DataGridViewButtonCell` em cada `DataGridViewRow` que faz interseção nele. Cada célula fornece uma interface de usuário (IU) que é semelhante a um controle `Button`.

Para redefinir o texto no botão de cada célula, defina a propriedade `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` como `true` e ajuste a propriedade `Text` para o texto do botão desejado.

Como você não colocou nenhuma amostra do seu código, eu ter que criar um exemplo fictício e fica seu critério o adaptar para sua realidade.

Nesse exemplo vou adicionar um objeto do tipo `DataGridViewButtonColumn`chamado `bColumn1` a um objeto do tipo `DataGridView` chamado dataGridView1.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn bColumn1 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
bColumn1.Name = "bColumn1";
bColumn1.Text = "Remover Linha";
int columnIndex = 0;
if (dataGridView1.Columns["bColumn1"] == null)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, bColumn1);
}
```

Crio um evento para manipular o clique.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["bColumn1"].Index)
    {
        // Aqui vai o código para apagar sua linha do Banco de Dados.
        // A propriedade e.RowIndex determina a linha a qual foi clicada.
    }
}
```

Adicionando o evento `CellClick`.

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += dataGridView1_CellClick;
```

Para colocar a imagem em cada botão você manipula o evento [`DataGridView.CellPainting`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender,
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e){

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0){

       // Você pode usar e.RowIndex para decidir qual a imagem usada por cada linha

       e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

       var w = Properties.Resources.suaImage.Width;
       var h = Properties.Resources.suaImage.Height;
       var x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
       var y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

       e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.suaImage, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Adicione o evento `CellPainting`.

```
dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;
```

Comment: Bom dia! Na verdade não seria um botão mais uma imagem na celular, que vou utilizar como botão, mais com a imagem eu posso colocar algo que descreva o campo, já com o botão não tenho espaço para colocar o nome do campo.
Na foto que add no corpo da mensagem tem  campo na dataGridView o primeiro, ele so fica com aquela imagem.

Comment: Fiz uma edição adicionando imagem nos botões.